# What does `modprobe option` do?

Tags: linux, modprobe

In a script to enable a NovAtel USB cell modem on a Beagle Bone Black running Ubuntu, I saw this line:

```
/sbin/modprobe option
```

I looked at the `modprobe` man page, it says lots about options (note the s), but nothing about a singular `option`  argument. Is there a module called `option` or something?? Or does that have some other side effect they're eliciting to setup the modem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are absolutely right, `modprobe option` does attempt to load the module `option`, controlled by the kernel config parameter `USB_SERIAL_OPTION`.

Some more informations are found in the kernel sources (`drivers/usb/serial/Kconfig`)

```
config USB_SERIAL_OPTION
        tristate "USB driver for GSM and CDMA modems"
        (...)
          This driver also supports several PCMCIA cards which have a
        built-in OHCI-USB adapter and an internally-connected GSM modem.
        The USB bus on these cards is not accessible externally.
          Supported devices include (some of?) those made by:
        Option, Huawei, Audiovox, Novatel Wireless, or Anydata.
        (...)
          If this driver doesn't recognize your device,
        it might be accessible via the FTDI_SIO driver.
```

### How to track this down:

1. Check, if you have such a kernel module (this is only working, if it's enabled in your kernel config)

   ```
   $ find /lib/modules -name option.ko
   /lib/modules/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/option.ko
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can try if the module loads

   ```
   # modprobe option
   # lsmod | grep option
   option                 33128  0 
   usb_wwan               13044  1 option
   usbserial              23912  2 option,usb_wwan
   ```
3. Now, you can try to find the source files (this only works if the module is included in your current kernel sources)

   ```
   $ find /usr/src/linux -name option.c
   /usr/src/linux/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/core/core/option.c
   /usr/src/linux/drivers/usb/serial/option.c
   ```

   You mentioned, the module has something todo with a USB modem, so the second match sounds promising.
4. You can also find the kernel config parameter

   ```
   $ find /usr/src/linux -name Makefile -exec grep -H option\.o '{}' \;
   /usr/src/linux/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/Makefile:nouveau-y += core/core/option.o
   /usr/src/linux/drivers/usb/serial/Makefile:obj-$(CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_OPTION)                   += option.o
   ```

   Now, you can have a look at `/usr/src/linux/drivers/usb/serial/Kconfig` and find the description I quoted at the beginning.
5. Finally, have a look at the source itself (`.../drivers/usb/serial/option.c`), and *voilà* you find among other things **the author's explanation of the name**

   > This driver exists because the "normal" serial driver doesn't work too well   with GSM modems. Issues:
   >
   > - data loss -- one single Receive URB is not nearly enough
   > - nonstandard flow (Option devices) control
   > - controlling the baud rate doesn't make sense
   >
   >   **This driver is named "option" because the most common device it's
   >
   >     used for is a PC-Card (with an internal OHCI-USB interface, behind
   >
   >     which the GSM interface sits), made by Option Inc.**
   >
   >   Some of the "one port" devices actually exhibit multiple USB
   >     instances   on the USB bus. This is not a bug, these ports are used
   >     for different   device features.

Comment: Amazing. And no one stopped to think, "I wonder if having a module named option, won't confuse the heck out of people." Thanks!

Comment: @TravisGriggs I expanded my answer with an guideline how to track such questions down (,,Give a man a fish and he will eat for a day. Teach a man to fish and he will eat for the rest of his life.'') and an explanation for the name. TL;DR: You shouldn't blame the module's author, but the company which name itself _Option_ `;)`.

Comment: Learned so valuable things here!

Comment: I wonder, if it could be renamed, leaving only a mere alias for a backward compatibility? 'cause it's really very confusing.